# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint Error when updating products via CRON

Tags: magento-1.8, php, database, mysql, cron

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento_database`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_VAL_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_produc)
```

I have scoured the internet but nothing seems to work. I have seen the Magento DB repair tool but I believe that would make things more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update a row in `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, but the foreign key on `catalog_product_entity` (I guess) is missing.

Therefore you try to write a media gallery image, without having a product.

The solution for this is, to check why the entry in `catalog_product_entity` doesn't exist. Maybe the `product_id` value on your write to `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` is `null`?

It is no problem with the defined foreign key, but with enforcing of this dependency.

Be careful when debugging this. This may all happen inside a transaction, then it is hard to look inside it - at least I don't know how to do this.

Comment: How do I restore the foreign key? ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_VAL_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` (`value_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;  didn't work either.

Comment: added more details.